# Insert_id fails to return a value

Tags: php, insert, mysqli

Can anyone see what is wrong with the code below? For some reason i can get it to return the id of the affected row..in fact it doesnt return anything but the query runs fine and the record is created in the db...

```
        $stmt = $this->db->stmt_init();
        if($stmt->prepare('INSERT INTO Assets(id,assetName,type, username, password, mail) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)'))
        {           
            $stmt->bind_param("isssss", $id, $assetName, $type, $username, $password, $mail);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            return $stmt->insert_id;
        }
        else
        {
            $stmt->close();            
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: Never mind I just noticed that I am closing the statement before I return...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing the statements before trying to get the insert id:

```
$stmt->close();
return $stmt->insert_id;
```